# evaluate the output of autoML results

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

How do I interpret following results? What is the best possible algorithm to train based on autogluon summary?

```
*** Summary of fit() ***
Estimated performance of each model:
                                    model  score_val     fit_time  pred_time_val  stack_level
19                weighted_ensemble_k0_l2  -0.035874     1.848907       0.002517            2
18                weighted_ensemble_k0_l1  -0.040987     1.837416       0.002259            1
16          CatboostClassifier_STACKER_l1  -0.042901  1559.653612       0.083949            1
11    ExtraTreesClassifierGini_STACKER_l1  -0.047882     7.307266       1.057873            1
...
...
0   RandomForestClassifierGini_STACKER_l0  -0.291987     9.871649       1.054538            0
```

The code to generate the above results:

```
import pandas as pd
from autogluon import TabularPrediction as task
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits

digits = load_digits()
savedir = "otto_models/"  # where to save trained models

train_data = pd.DataFrame(digits.data)
train_target = pd.DataFrame(digits.target)
train_data = pd.merge(train_data, train_target, left_index=True, right_index=True)
label_column = "0_y"

predictor = task.fit(
    train_data=train_data,
    label=label_column,
    output_directory=savedir,
    eval_metric="log_loss",
    auto_stack=True,
    verbosity=2,
    visualizer="tensorboard",
)

results = predictor.fit_summary()  # display detailed summary of fit() process
```

Which algorithm seems to work in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

weighted_ensemble_k0_l2 is the best result in terms of validation score (score_val) because it has the highest value. You may wish to do `predictor.leaderboard(test_data)` to get the test scores for each of the models.

Note that the result shows a negative score because AutoGluon always considers higher to be better. If a particular metric such as logloss prefers lower values to be better, AutoGluon flips the sign of the metric. I would guess a val_score of 0 would be a perfect score in your case.

Comment: Does it mean -0.03 score_val is something like 97% accuracy?

Comment: No, it would be 0.97 in that case. -0.03 given your provided code would mean 0.03 logloss.